# ¿Me devuelve un argumento donde deberian retornar dos en vistas de django?

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes queridos amigos de stackoverflow tengo esta duda, estoy intentando imprimir pdfs desde django con la libreria xhtml2pdf para mis proyectos en **django2.0**, sigo un tutorial que me parece interesante que la fuente es:

https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/

Mi error en pantalla es el siguiente:

**__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

Sigo al pie de la letra el tutorial de alli arriba, a lo mejor sea por la version de Django pero les pondre mi codigo aquí abajo

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from .pdf_generator import render_to_pdf
class GeneratePdf(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/invoice.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

**pdf_generator.py**

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
     return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('pdf/', views.GeneratePdf),
]
```

**pdf-generator.html**

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}

{% block content_style %}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
    color: #333333;
}
{% endblock content_style %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <h2>Welcome to the pdf!</h2>
{% endblock content %}
```

por si acaso les dejo algo llamado el **traceback**:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cv/pdf/

Django Version: 2.0
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['main.apps.SuitConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'phonenumber_field',
 'django_countries',
 'material',
 'material.frontend',
 'cv']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'material.frontend.middleware.SmoothNavigationMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /cv/pdf/
Exception Value: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Disculpen tanto codigo es que deseo ser lo más explicito posible porque de verdad no se que hacer he intentado con varias librerias y siempre es este error el cual persiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar las Vistas Basadas en Clase tienes que llamar a su método `as_view()`. Por lo tanto, tienes que modificar tu URL de esta manera:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('pdf/', views.GeneratePdf.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: De verdad muy agradecido fue esto lo que necesitaba.